# How can I prevent the direct call of an URL in an ASP.NET / IIS environment?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

How can I achieve in an ASP.NET application, that a set of URLs/ASPX pages (parts of the application) cannot be called directly from the user in the Browser? These urls/pages may only be referenced in the application itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If a user can get to a page, they will be able to call it directly. You can't control peoples browsers...

One option is to look at the ["HTTP_REFERER"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header and if it is empty or has an unexpected value redirect. This does mean that your application will have to set it.

Another one is to create a custom header ("X-my-app", for instance) and if it does not exist, redirect.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is called the Referrer with an additional R since the people of W3C failed their spelling checks... :-) It should have been HTTP_REFERRER... But indeed, check the referrer to check the previous page. If it's an unexpected value, redirect to somewhere else. (With ASP.NET, you could add this logic into a master page, but then your index page should make an exception for all visitors.)